# C# Task does not act like what I expect

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, difference

First, I implemented test logic with Thread:

```
    public void ThreadProc()
    {
        Console.Write("s");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.Write("e");
    }

    public void TestByThread()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
            t.Start();
        }
    }
```

When Run TestByThread(), Result is like this:

sssssssssseeeeeeeeee

But When It comes to Task...

```
    public void TestByTask()
    {

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.Write("s");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.Write("e");
            });
        }
    }
```

When execute TestByTask(), Result is strange:

ssssssseesesseeeeeee

Not only char order, but also output speed is different.

What's the difference between Task and Thread?

Comment: The question is very broad - Tasks and Threads are very different concepts. Have you read the documentation and guides about both of them? Is there some specific aspect that you do not understand? As-is the question seems to imply that you expect them to act the same, so I would recommend you first read the documentation and then narrow down your question some.

Comment: This question is not broad as it has two sample codes and two sample results and op wants to know difference in execution. Having in depth knowledge and reading documentation would solve this question anyway, then why come and populate SO anyway? People come here to share knowledge that others may have. Just simply telling op to read documentation is as good as telling not to use SO for anything at all. Question is very valid and quite narrow to be on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `Thread.Start` a new thread is created, and all threads prints `s` and then wait and all of them print `e`.

In case of `Task.Run`, Tasks only have few threads in thread pool. It seems little odd as only 7 threads are available in pool, may be some threads are busy doing something. So 7 times task prints `s`, and all of them go in sleep, however, there are still more tasks in queue that didn't start at all.

When some of tasks that were in pool finished (that printed `e`), those tasks were available to run new Task, so it then started rest of tasks in pending.

Answer (score 3):

`Thread.Start()` starts a new thread, where `Task.Run()` schedules a task. The task is then executed by the next available worker thread. It can happen that a new thread is created, but don't rely on that.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example you are manually creating 10 threads and running them in parallel. And since each thread is waiting for 1 second before writing `"e"`, all the 10 `"s"` are already written because of the parallelism.

When you use `Task.Run` you are instructing the CLR to start a new task as soon as there's one available worker in the pool. Usually you will have as many workers in the pool as CPU cores (but this is not a guarantee), so basically even if you call `Task.Run` 10 times, this doesn't mean that 10 threads will start working immediately. Quite on the contrary it will only start as many tasks as are available currently in the pool and then the others will wait for the first tasks to finish before starting again.